# Python won't write to file unless it already exists: permissions related issue

Tags: python

I've got the following Python code:

```
class Server(object):

  def __init__(self, options):
    self.data_file = '/etc/my_module/resources.json'

  # Triggered when new data is received
  def write(self, data):
    try:
      f = open(self.data_file, 'w')
      json.dump(data, f)
    except Exception, e:
      print e
    finally:
      f.close()
```

If the file `/etc/my_module/resources.json` does not exist then I get an error message when I call the `write` method:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/my_module/resources.json'
```

If I create the file manually and call the write method again, then everything works and the json is written to the file.

I'm running my application with sudo: `sudo python my_module.py`, and I've added my user (vagrant) to `/etc/sudoers`.

So python won't create the file if it doesn't exist, on the grounds that it doesn't have permission to write to /etc, but it will happily write to the file if it does exist. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
f = open(self.data_file, 'w')
```

To

```
f = open(self.data_file, 'w+')
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new file involves writing a new file entry to the directory which requires write permissions on the directory. Modifying an existing file bypasses this.

Comment: Assuming he's running the file using sudo wouldn't it have those necessary write permissions?

Comment: That would imply that `O_CREAT` is not set in the `open(2)` call, which sounds like an OS bug.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out @iChar got the right answer above, I needed to use `open(self.data_file, 'w+')`.

Comment: @marflar: But that doesn't fully explain *why*. (Not that mine does either.)